# Why six blanks and five blanks result in same effect?

Tags: html, blank-line

Why six blanks and five blanks result in same effect?

```
<html>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hello<br/>hello<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hello<br/>hello<br/>
</html>
```

To open it with firefox.

[image]

1. The are different effect.

2.still problem for

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hello<br/>hello<br/>
```

There are five blanks here ,why only three blanks displayed on the web page?

[image]

Comment: It's not the "same effect", look closer

Comment: Use a non-proportional font or, better yet, use a `CSS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect is not clearly the same. But I think what @it_is_a_literature meant was why is the "h" in first line starting from the second "l" from the second line.
My answer to it is that, not every character has a equal width or dimensions. For eg. the "l" in hello takes less space than "e" in the same word.

The " " works like a space bar. So there are 5 spaces not 3.

Comment: To PeterAronZentai's point, you can use the `<samp>` tag to get monospaced output (but that's not what you want here; use padding as others suggest).

Answer (score 16):

It clearly shows its not the same effect.
[image]

Comment: sorry for my  carelessness.

Comment: And it is always better to use padding-left or margin-left in css to do this kind of indentation.

Answer (score 4):

One &nbsp is one extra space before your content. So it cannot show the same result. You can use pure css for that matter.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style='padding-left:0px;'>Hello</div>
    <div style='padding-left:50px;'>Hello</div>
    <div style='padding-left:25px;'>Hello</div>
    <div style='padding-left:0px;'>Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Using `&nbsp;` is not a good approach. Instead use css padding to achieve the required effect.

Answer (score 1):

Main font families haven't a **regular size** for each character (eg. : 'l' is thinner than 'L'). In other words, 5 spaces takes small place than 5 characters in "hello".

If you need regular character spacing (making ASCII art ?), you should use **monospace** font family like *Courrier* or *Lucida Console* with a CSS class like so :

`.monospace {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}`

Here is a [Plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/CuJarxKYkywbM2KThtva?p=preview) to see the differences.